# Variadic functions not working on arduino

Tags: arduino, variadic-functions, avr-gcc, avrdude

I'm trying to write my own basic libraries to program the Arduino in pure C++. I've tried using a variadic function to implement something similar to Linux's `ioctl()` to control the SPI module but it just won't work and I have no idea why. I don't pin 13 (Arduino SCK) light up as expected during SPI transactions indicating that SPI is not operating. All the other functions in my library work properly.

The following is my SPI library:

```
/*
    spi.h:  SPI driver for Atmega328p
*/

#ifndef     _SPI_H
#define     _SPI_H

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

// SPI bus pin mapping ///////////////////////////////////

#define PORT_SPI    PORTB           // Port register containing SPI pins
#define DDR_SPI     DDRB            // Data direction register containing SPI pins

#define DDR_SCK     DDB5            // Data direction bit of SPI SCK pin
#define DDR_MISO    DDB4            // Data direction bit of SPI MISO pin
#define DDR_MOSI    DDB3            // Data direction bit of SPI MOSI pin
#define DDR_HWCS    DDB2            // Data direction bit of SPI hardware chip select pin

#define PIN_SCK     PB5             // Port register bit of SPI SCK pin
#define PIN_MISO    PB4             // Port register bit of SPI MISO pin
#define PIN_MOSI    PB3             // Port register bit of SPI MOSI pin
#define PIN_HWCS    PB2             // Port register bit of SPI hardware chip select pin

// SPI ioctl commands ////////////////////////////////////

#define SPIIOCCONF          0       // Configure SPI command
#define SPIIOCDECONF        1       // Deconfigure SPI command
#define SPIIOCTRANSMIT      2       // SPI byte exchange command

// Clock frequency settings //////////////////////////////

#define SCK_DIV2    2               // Divide source pulse by 2
#define SCK_DIV4    4               // Divide source pulse by 4
#define SCK_DIV8    8               // Divide source pulse by 8
#define SCK_DIV16   16              // Divide source pulse by 16
#define SCK_DIV32   32              // Divide source pulse by 32
#define SCK_DIV64   64              // Divide source pulse by 64
#define SCK_DIV128  128             // Divide source pulse by 128

// SPI modes /////////////////////////////////////////////

#define SPI_MODE0   0
#define SPI_MODE1   1
#define SPI_MODE2   2
#define SPI_MODE3   3

// SPI transaction data orders ///////////////////////////

#define LSBFIRST    0
#define MSBFIRST    1

// The SPI module ////////////////////////////////////////

class spiModule {

    private:
            bool    configured;                             // Indicates whether SPI is operating with a valid configuration

            uint8_t ddrOld, portOld;                        // Value of DDR_SPI and PORT_SPI just before an SPI configuration was called for
                                                            // ( These variables are used to restore the state of the
                                                            // SPI pins when SPI is deconfigured )

            /* ioctls used to operate the SPI module */

            void    spiiocconf(int, int, int);              // Configure SPI with a valid clock frequency, data order and SPI mode
            void    spiiocdeconf(void);                     // Deconfigure SPI and restore SPI pins to their original states
            void    spiioctransmit(uint8_t, uint8_t *);     // Exchange a byte of data over SPI

            /* ioctl handlers */
            /* These routines check the validity of the arguments and call the ioctls (above) only if all arguments make sense */
            /* I've tested these functions by making them public and found that they work perfectly */

            int     conf(int, int, int);                    // call spiiocconf() if arguments are valid and SPI is configured
            int     deconf(void);                           // call spiiocdeconf() if all arguments are valid and SPI is configured
            int     transmit(uint8_t, uint8_t *);           // call spiioctransmit() if all arguments are valid and SPI is configured

    public:
                    spiModule(void);                        // Initialize this class
            int     ioctl(int action, ... );                // Core ioctl handler (supposed to work like the Linux ioctl() system call). But this one just won't work.
};

spiModule spi;                                              // Object of class spiModule for using SPI

// Constructor ///////////////////////////////////////////

spiModule::spiModule(void) {

    configured = false;
}

// Private routines //////////////////////////////////////

/* Ioctls */

void        spiModule::spiiocconf(int clkDiv, int dataOrder, int mode) {

    // Store the values of DDR_SPI and PORT_SPI so they may be recovered when SPI is deconfigured

    ddrOld = DDR_SPI;
    portOld = PORT_SPI;

    // Configure SCK, MOSI and HWCS as output pins and MISO as an input pin

    DDR_SPI |= (_BV(DDR_HWCS) | _BV(DDR_SCK) | _BV(DDR_MOSI));
    DDR_SPI &= ~_BV(DDR_MISO);

    // Power up the SPI module

    PRR &= ~_BV(PRSPI);

    // Enable SPI and configure it as master

    SPCR = 0x00;
    SPCR |= (_BV(SPE) | _BV(MSTR));

    // Set data order

    switch(dataOrder)
    {
            case    LSBFIRST:
                    SPCR |= _BV(DORD);
                    break;

            case    MSBFIRST:
                    SPCR &= ~_BV(DORD);
                    break;
    }

    // Set SPI mode

    switch(mode)
    {
            case    SPI_MODE0:
                    SPCR &= ~(_BV(CPOL) | _BV(CPHA));
                    break;

            case    SPI_MODE1:
                    SPCR |= _BV(CPHA);
                    SPCR &= ~_BV(CPOL);
                    break;

            case    SPI_MODE2:
                    SPCR &= ~_BV(CPHA);
                    SPCR |= _BV(CPOL);
                    break;

            case    SPI_MODE3:
                    SPCR |= (_BV(CPOL) | _BV(CPHA));
                    break;
    }

    // Set SPI clock frequency

    switch(clkDiv)
    {
            case    SCK_DIV2:
                    SPCR &= ~(_BV(SPR0) | _BV(SPR1));
                    SPSR |= _BV(SPI2X);
                    break;

            case    SCK_DIV4:
                    SPCR &= ~(_BV(SPR0) | _BV(SPR1));
                    SPSR &= ~_BV(SPI2X);
                    break;

            case    SCK_DIV8:
                    SPCR |= _BV(SPR0);
                    SPCR &= ~_BV(SPR1);
                    SPSR |= _BV(SPI2X);
                    break;

            case    SCK_DIV16:
                    SPCR |= _BV(SPR0);
                    SPCR &= ~_BV(SPR1);
                    SPSR &= ~_BV(SPI2X);
                    break;

            case    SCK_DIV32:
                    SPCR &= ~_BV(SPR0);
                    SPCR |= _BV(SPR1);
                    SPSR |= _BV(SPI2X);
                    break;

            case    SCK_DIV64:
                    SPCR |= _BV(SPR0);
                    SPCR |= _BV(SPR1);
                    SPSR |= _BV(SPI2X);
                    break;

            case    SCK_DIV128:
                    SPCR |= _BV(SPR0);
                    SPCR |= _BV(SPR1);
                    SPSR &= ~_BV(SPI2X);
                    break;
    }

    // SPI is now configured

    configured = true;
    return;
}

void        spiModule::spiiocdeconf(void) {

    // Clear SPI configuration, power down the SPI module and restore the values of DDR_SPI and PORT_SPI

    SPCR = 0x00;
    PRR |= _BV(PRSPI);

    DDR_SPI = ddrOld;
    PORT_SPI = portOld; 

    // SPI is no longer configured

    configured = false;

    return;
}

void        spiModule::spiioctransmit(uint8_t txbyte, uint8_t * rxbyte) {

    // Write TX byte to data register

    SPDR = txbyte;
    while(!(SPSR & _BV(SPIF)))
    {
            /* wait for data transmission to complete */
    }
    SPSR &= ~_BV(SPIF);

    // Return RX byte by storing it at the specified location

    if(rxbyte != NULL)
    {
            *rxbyte = SPDR;
    }

    return;
}

/* Ioctl handlers (verify that all arguments are appropriate and only then proceed with the ioctl) */

int         spiModule::conf(int clkDiv, int dataOrder, int mode) {

    // Return with error of SPI is not configured

    if(!configured)
    {
            return -1;
    }

    // Verify validity of clkDiv (clock pulse division factor)

    switch(clkDiv)
    {
            case    SCK_DIV2:
                    break;
            case    SCK_DIV4:
                    break;
            case    SCK_DIV8:
                    break;
            case    SCK_DIV16:
                    break;
            case    SCK_DIV32:
                    break;
            case    SCK_DIV64:
                    break;
            case    SCK_DIV128:
                    break;
            default:
                    return -1;
    }

    // Verify validity of dataOrder (order of byte transfer)

    switch(dataOrder)
    {
            case    LSBFIRST:
                    break;
            case    MSBFIRST:
                    break;
            default:
                    return -1;
    }

    // Check validity of mode (SPI mode)

    switch(mode)
    {
            case    SPI_MODE0:
                    break;
            case    SPI_MODE1:
                    break;
            case    SPI_MODE2:
                    break;
            case    SPI_MODE3:
                    break;
            default:
                    return -1;
    }

    // If all goes well, execute the ioctl

    spiiocconf(clkDiv, dataOrder, mode);

    return 0;
}

int         spiModule::deconf(void) {

    // If SPI is configured, deconfigure it

    if(!configured)
    {
            return -1;
    }

    spiiocdeconf();

    return 0;
}

int         spiModule::transmit(uint8_t tx, uint8_t * rx) {

    // If SPI is configured, make a byte exchange

    if(!configured)
    {
            return -1;
    }

    spiioctransmit(tx, rx);

    return 0;
}

// Public routines ///////////////////////////////////////

int         spiModule::ioctl(int action, ... ) {

    // This routine checks the value of action and executes the respective ioctl
    // It returns with error if the value of action is not valid

    va_list ap;

    int     clkDiv, dataOrder, mode;
    uint8_t txbyte;
    uint8_t * rxbyte;

    int     retVal;

    switch(action)
    {
            case    SPIIOCCONF:

                    va_start(ap, action);

                    clkDiv = va_arg(ap, int);
                    dataOrder = va_arg(ap, int);
                    mode = va_arg(ap, int);

                    va_end(ap);

                    retVal = conf(clkDiv, dataOrder, mode);
                    return retVal;

            case    SPIIOCDECONF:

                    retVal = deconf();
                    return retVal;

            case    SPIIOCTRANSMIT:

                    va_start(ap, action);

                    txbyte = va_arg(ap, uint8_t);
                    rxbyte = va_arg(ap, uint8_t*);

                    va_end(ap);

                    retVal = transmit(txbyte, rxbyte);
                    return retVal;

            default:
                    return -1;
    }
}

#endif
```

I'm compiling and uploading my code to the Arduino using the following commands (`spiTest.cpp` is a code that I used to test this library)

```
COMPILER=~/Softwares/arduino-1.6.8/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-g++
HEXGENERATOR=~/Softwares/arduino-1.6.8/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avr-objcopy
UPLOADER=~/Softwares/arduino-1.6.8/hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude

AVRDUDE_CFG=~/Softwares/arduino-1.6.8/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf

$COMPILER -c -g -w -D F_CPU=16000000UL -mmcu=atmega328p -std=gnu++11 -o spiTest.o spiTest.cpp
$COMPILER -mmcu=atmega328p spiTest.o -o spiTest

$HEXGENERATOR -O ihex -R .eeprom spiTest spiTest.hex

$UPLOADER -C $AVRDUDE_CFG -v -p atmega328p -c arduino -P /dev/ttyACM0 -b 115200 -D -U flash:w:spiTest.hex:i
```

I've used variadic functions to implement `ioctl()` before and it worked when I used the Arduino IDE to compile and upload my program. I don't understand what's preventing variadic functions from working properly in this code.

Answer (score 0):

You are in the C++, you can do it in better. For example something like:

```
class      SPIIOCONF_t {}      SPIIOCONF;
class   SPIIOCDECONF_t {}   SPIIOCDECONF;
class SPIIOCTRANSMIT_t {} SPIIOCTRANSMIT;

int ioctl(SPIIOCONF_t, int clkDiv, int dataOrder, int mode) {
  return conf(clkDiv, dataOrder, mode);
}

int ioctl(SPIIOCDECONF_t) {
  return deconf();
}

int ioctl(SPIIOCTRANSMIT_t, uint8_t txbyte, uint8_t rxbyte) {
  return transmit(txbyte, rxbyte);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  Serial.println(ioctl(SPIIOCONF, 10, 1, 1));
  Serial.println(ioctl(SPIIOCDECONF));

  uint8_t rx;
  Serial.println(ioctl(SPIIOCTRANSMIT, 0xFF, &rx));
}
```

or similarly without defining dummy class instance, but you have to create one in the call:

```
class      SPIIOCONF {};
class   SPIIOCDECONF {};
class SPIIOCTRANSMIT {};

int ioctl(SPIIOCONF, int clkDiv, int dataOrder, int mode) {
  return conf(clkDiv, dataOrder, mode);
}

int ioctl(SPIIOCDECONF) {
  return deconf();
}

int ioctl(SPIIOCTRANSMIT, uint8_t txbyte, uint8_t rxbyte) {
  return transmit(txbyte, rxbyte);
}

void setup() {
  ioctl(SPIIOCONF{}, 10, 1, 1);

  uint8_t rx;
  Serial.println(ioctl(SPIIOCTRANSMIT{}, 0xFF, &rx));

  ioctl(SPIIOCDECONF{});
}
```

Comment: Well... That should work but I'm curious why variadic functions don't work while manually compiling if they work when I use the arduino IDE.